# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception, ocpjp

I am trying to execute simple query using below DbQuery.java class which uses DbConnector to get a Connection from DriverManager.

**note**:

1. I have already included "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" on my
   classpath via: export
   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/me/ocpjp/chapter-10/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
2. I am able to connect to mysql with "mysql -uroot -ptcial
   addressBook", if it matters.
3. have also tried running with '-cp'
   argument with no avail.
4. I am able to get my #3 DbConnect.java class to say "Database connection established".
5. Also #4 **DbQueryWorking.java has no issues** and provides expected output .

Can you please help me understand what is the issue here ?

1) DbConnector.java

```
package com.me.ocpjp.chapter10;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnector{
public static Connection connectToDb() throws SQLException{
String url = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/";
String db = "addressBook";
String username = "root";
String password = "tcial";
return DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, username, password);
}

}
```

2) DbQuery.java

```
package com.me.ocpjp.chapter10;

import java.sql.Connection  ;
import java.sql.Statement  ;
import java.sql.ResultSet  ;
import java.sql.SQLException  ;
import com.me.ocpjp.chapter10.DbConnector;

public class DbQuery{
public static void main(String[] args){
try(Connection connection = DbConnector.connectToDb();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from contact")){
System.out.println("ID \tfName \tlName \temail \t\tphoneNo");
while(resultSet.next()){
System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("id") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("firstName") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("lastName") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("email") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("phoneNo") );
}

}catch(SQLException sqle){
sqle.printStackTrace();
System.exit(-1);
}

}
}
```

3) DbConnect.java

```
package com.me.ocpjp.chapter10;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;



public class DbConnect{
public static void main(String[] args){

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database = "addressBook";
String userName = "root";
String password = "tcial";

try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+database, userName, password)){
System.out.println("Database connection established");
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Database connectioni NOT  established");
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

4) DbQueryWorking.java

```
package com.me.ocpjp.chapter10;

import java.sql.Connection  ;
import java.sql.Statement  ;
import java.sql.ResultSet  ;
import java.sql.SQLException  ;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DbQuery{
public static void main(String[] args){
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database = "addressBook";
String userName = "root";
String password = "tcial";
try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + database, userName, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from contact")){
System.out.println("ID \tfName \tlName \temail \t\tphoneNo");
while(resultSet.next()){
System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("id") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("firstName") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("lastName") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("email") + "\t"
+ resultSet.getString("phoneNo") );
}

}catch(SQLException sqle){
sqle.printStackTrace();
System.exit(-1);
}

}
}
```

Comment: can you please post the **full** stack trace?

Comment: i think we don't need that anymore . thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it looks like that the URL in `DbConnector.java` is wrong. A colon is missing. The url must be:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

and not

```
jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/
```

Answer (score 4):

your URL is wrong, you're missing a colon in it, it should be:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
```