# "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" when connecting to Pi database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a Raspberry Pi running a mysql server which is working fine and I can connect to it with it's ip address (192.168.1.90) (local, for now), and see the databases and tables etc which are stored on it.
I have it set up with phpmyadmin where I have created a database called "world" which has a number of tables.

I've tried to connect to it with java with the following code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.90/world", "root", "mypass");
```

However this gives me an error message:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

I know that the username and password are both correct since I can use them and successfully when I execute the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I use my android phone for developing but since it's connected to the wifi that shouldn't be a problem (I can reach 192.168.1.90 fine).

I've been out of the game for a couple of weeks and it feels like there is something I'm missing, but I don't see it.

**EDIT: I did not compile the .jar for the mysql connector in the gradle file.** However, I now get another error which says:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

Thanks for taking the time to read about my problem. All help is appreciated!

Comment: There are numerous questions on this topic [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507449/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found) . Did you try all of them first, before asking? (there are 2-3 more, I copied just a few).

Comment: I forgot that I had to add the jar file to the lib folder and compile that in the gradle file... However, now I get an error "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server."
Do I need to have the .jar on the pi somehow?

Comment: Dunno, keep googling :D